# Add Space between LinearLayouts

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a list of database items like the following..

```
   for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
           {

               JSONObject row = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

               LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
               ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,100));

               Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
               //btn.setText(row.getString("subject"));
               btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
               btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(float)0.8));


               File imgFile = new  File(file_path);

               Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

               ImageView iv = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
               iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
               iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
               iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(float)0.2));




               ll.addView(btn);
               ll.addView(iv);

               LinearLayout sv = findViewById(R.id.sv_layout);
               sv.addView(ll);

           }
```

The result is like this:
[image: List Of Items]

But I want to have space between Linear Layouts and make Image height shorter to be equal with button height
[image: [see this]]

How can I achieve this? Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried adding padding to the ImageView?

Comment: make a custom view so you can handle it easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the margins in the layout params and pass them to your ImageView object.

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(float)0.2);
            int dp = getDps(8);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,dp,0,dp);
            iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Function getDps():

```
public int getDps(int sizeInDp){
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return  (int) (sizeInDp*scale + 0.5f);
    }
```

This looks like: [image]

Comment: @xbadal Edited!

Comment: All answers are right and I voted them up , But it seems you've spent more time..

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this code

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
                    params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 10);
                    ll.setLayoutParams(params);
```

you can add your specific margins in this line `params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 10);`

Answer (score 1):

Take button and image in linear layout with horizontal orientation. Set Button and Imageview height to **wrap content**. Now for gap between Linear Layouts give appropriate **margin**.